# Insert multiple users and random passwords Php&mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I am struggling to create multiple user&password and insert it in mysql column.
inserting multiple username is working but not multiple random password.

**mysql table "users" - columns 'user' & 'password'  primary key = user column**

How it works:

A user enters a username and numbers (how many user & pass to create) in an HTML form.

The code uses the submitted username and adds a serial from "1" to limit (submitted number).

Example input:

- submitted user is john
- submitted numbers is 20

Example result:

- john1, john2... john20

In the future when the user requests another 10 user & pass with same name "john" the number will start from 21 (john21, john22... john30)
adding another series is not done yet any help and tips are welcome.

My code:

```
function muser() {
    function randomPassword() {
        $alphabet = "abcdefghjkmnpqrstuwxyz23456789"; // skip 0OoIl1
        $pass = array();
        $alphaLength = strlen($alphabet) - 1; 
        for ($i = 0; $i < 6; $i++) {
            $n = rand(0, $alphaLength);
            $pass[] = $alphabet[$n];
        }
        return implode($pass); 
    }

    if(isset($_REQUEST['submit'])) {
        $user_input_user = $_REQUEST["user"];
        $user_input_limit = $_REQUEST["limit"];

        $ipass = randomPassword();
    } 

    $uiuser = $user_input_user;
    $uilimit = $user_input_limit;


    $limit = $uilimit; 
    for($x = 1; $x <= $limit; $x++) {
        $queryuser[] = "('$uiuser$x', '$ipass'),";
    }
    return implode($queryuser);
 }

 $mquery = 'INSERT INTO `users` (`user`, `pass`) VALUES ';
 $imuser = muser();
 $fquery = substr($imuser, 0, -1);
 $sql =  $mquery . $fquery .';';
```

Comment: why cant you add PK id append with each username

Comment: user column is already PK, and is working fine, the issue is adding multiple password.... for this example I am getting 20 unique users and 20 same password :(

Comment: then password can append with PK..?

Comment: not working but I think the issue is the random password generated by 'function randomPassword()'. this function is only executed once instead of multiple times as entered in form (limit)

Comment: You want different passwords for the same batch of user ids?

Comment: @Capital C... Yes

Comment: Then move the random password function call in into the query building loop.

Comment: $password=md5(uniqid(rand(), true)); as password...no need for generate another unique password

Comment: Hard to show code in comments. I just removed it.

Comment: @ Safin chacko / Capital C Thanks!!! I moved the password function into building loop and it works!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is caused because you give value to $ipass only once.

change the for loop from this

```
for($x = 1; $x <= $limit; $x++) {
    $queryuser[] = "('$uiuser$x', '$ipass'),";
}
```

to

```
for($x = 1; $x <= $limit; $x++) {
    $queryuser[] = "('$uiuser$x', '$ipass'),";
    $ipass = randomPassword();
}
```